# Getting Feature and Geometry error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

This is the code:

```
//print('Amsterdam', Amsterdam)
var Cent_Amsterdam = ee.Feature(geometry);
Map.addLayer(Cent_Amsterdam, {}, 'Cent_Amsterdam');
Map.centerObject(Cent_Amsterdam, 10);

var first = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/CO2/T1_L2')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
  .filterBounds(Cent_Amsterdam)
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
  .first();

Map.addLayer(first.clip(Cent_Amsterdam), {bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'], min: 7000, max: 15000});
```

This is the error:

```
Layer 2: Layer error: Feature, argument 'geometry': Invalid type.
Expected type: Geometry.
Actual type: Feature.
```

Just trying to get a Landsat overlay on Google Earth Engine of Amsterdam.
Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Looks like you are providing an ee.Feature type instead of ee.Geometry to the clip method. Can you try `first.clip(Cent_Amsterdam.geometry())`? That should extract the geometry information as input to the clip

Comment: I just get this error: ```Map: Layer error: Image.clip: Parameter 'input' is required.```